# How can we deal with different HTTP response from error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm working on simple authentication with my backend.

My action can't handle try-catch and I have no idea why it's not working as I expected because it worked a month ago.

```
export const doAuthLogin = ( username, password ) => async dispatch => {
  console.log('passing action'); <- print 'passing action'
  let response = await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/rest-auth/login/`, {
    username,
    password,
  }); <- shows 400 error on console (Expo)

  console.log(response.status); <- print nothing // well 200 can prints status here
  console.log('doesn't work); <- print nothing

  if (response.status === 200) { <- doesn't execute
```

Comment: I prefer not to doing .then and catch because it make the code dirty.. Um should I change whole actions??? I have more than 40 actions lol omg

Comment: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Request failed with status code 400

Comment: It is not necessary to use .then() and/or .catch() when using async/await. This is a newer syntax which is also meant to work with Promises. Both work equally as well, it just comes down to preference as to which you like best.

Comment: I can't remove .then and .catch because I have parallel promise requests. So second request has to wait (await) until we get the first response.

Comment: @NielsdeBruin And do you see any problem on my code?

Comment: i didn't have this problem before. This is very weird

Comment: axios.post(``${ROOT_URL}/rest-auth/login/``, { username, password }).catch(error => console.log(error));

Comment: ok, @MattyK14 I could print the error but how do we handle it? can you post an answer? such as... if(error.status===400) {dispatc(-)} ?? How do we handle different error?

Comment: I haven't used axios in a while, but from what it looks like axios returns a 400 response as an error. You're just not catching that error. The catch console.log(error) I posted is "catching" it, albeit as "boring" as possible. What does that console log tell you? How would you like to handle a 400?

Comment: I would handle both 400 and 404. For this specific case, I won't have a problem but when user enters Post Screen(Other thing), if the page is private so the logged in user is not supposed to see the post so it will send 404. OR if the token was expeired it will send 400 error (authorization bad request)

Comment: I can just print the 400 but I want to make everything smooth for client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `try-catch` block for a async operation (post). That's not correct. The operation runs and before there is a response (the "async" response) your code continues to run and end.

Your async operation must have a callback function parameter that deals with the response.

Comment: You are right. Do you see any problem on the first action??? It's so weird it can't get callback (response)

Comment: `let response = await axios.post(` should returns response and I was going to check whether its status is 200, 400, or 404.

Comment: Well interesting thing is that it can get 200.

Comment: I am not familiar with the library you are using (axios) but if it is async it should probably have a signature similar to this: axios.post(request, callback) or axios.post(request, success, error) or even (in jquery-style) axios.post(request).done(), etc. I recommend you check the jquery Ajax method to understand how this usually works. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Checked the axios briefly and it uses promises, so you have to do axios.post(request).then(<function to deal with success>).catch(function(err){ deal with err}).   All your code to deal with success /error needs to be inside then or catch.

Comment: I see. Thanks for reviewing it. for the summary, I think we need to use try { let response = await blah blah } catch (error) ...

Comment: This should work. Make sure your server is not the problem. If you are responsible for the server code, try debugging your request received, making sure it is well formed according to what it expects.

Comment: thanks for your time. Wish me good luck! :) haha have a great day

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify that it's an async function in the upper function as well.

```
export const doAuthLogin = async (username, password) => async dispatch => {
```

If that doesn't work, please create a jsfiddle/codepen with your entire codebase so we can investigate further.

Comment: Actions must be plain objects. Um I don't know how to use jsfiddle. And I don't think we can setup async request there :(

Comment: And for good news, I changed some questions. now question is how we can deal with diffferent error??